# Get location data for a program using GPS dongle

Tags: gps

I'm working on vehicle tracking system using GPS. What I want to do is connect GPS receiver to my laptop and fetch the location data in to my program. I have seen many commercial GPS receivers and dongles. Those devices providing there own driver software. Is there any way to fetch those location data in to my program using those devices.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are many ways, Which language you want to use ?

Comment: java or c++ is better

Answer (score 0):

The following projects could help you to collect the geolocation.

http://code.google.com/p/mygeoloc/

http://sourceforge.net/p/jgeocoder/code/HEAD/tree/

If you specified the device and its information Could provide much more information which you are looking for.

If you need a local database, you can check out what [IPInfoDB](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_database.php) has to offer.

Comment: what I want to do in get my current location